# Angular material checkbox optimize check using pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Currently i´m working in application where i need to filter an array of items, the filters need to be persistent, i save the filters and when i get the filters back i need to check which filters are active or not and change the check state of the checkbox.

[image]

for this im using a function `existInArray(element, array): boolean` that check is the filter is in the array of filters and return true or false

**Check is filter is active**

```
  public existInArray(element, array: Array<string>): boolean {
    if (!element) {
      return;
    }
    return array.indexOf(element.toString()) > -1;
  }
```

**Checkbox template**

```
<div class="filter-list-container m-top">
      <div *ngFor="let assignment of (filterService.getFilter(filterType.FILTER_ASSIGNMENT).items.ToArray() | filterQuery: filterOptions.assignments | sortBy: configService.config.sortUserBy:'assignment')">
         <mat-checkbox [checked]="existInArray(assignment.id, filterService.filterAssignment)"
            [ngClass]="{ 'checkbox-ie': platform.TRIDENT }"
            (change)="filterBy(filterType.FILTER_ASSIGNMENT, assignment.id, filterService.filterAssignment, assignment.name)"
            [value]="assignment.id">
             <div class="assigned">
               <user-image [inline]="true" [user]="assignment.assignment"></user-image>
                <p class="assigned-name">{{ assignment.name }}</p>
              </div>
            </mat-checkbox>
           </div>
          </div>
```

Now the function is working just fine, there is no error, but there is problem here, and is because of the angular change detection, the function is been call more than 1000 times, so i was thinking in maybe use a pipe but for some reason it did not work, any idea in which other way can i do this or maybe a way to optimize ( just in case i´m using angular material for the checkbox components ).

Comment: Note: You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of checking if [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is more than `-1`.

Comment: In this case it will the same, the function it will executing more than 1000 times because of the changeDetection from angular

Comment: try adding some metadata to `assignment`, e.g. `assignment.__checked__ = existInArray(....)` computed only when underlying data changes. and in html, `[checked]="assignment.__checked__ "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the problem, a pipe is the best way to do it, but because a pipe is only call when there is change in the value i need to pass a value that is gonna changing when there is a new filter in the filter array, so in this case i pass the length of the filter array

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:pipe-naming
  name: 'checkActiveCheckbox'
})
export class CheckActiveFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, arg?: Array<any>, change?: any): any {
    console.count('Filter PIPE');
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    return arg.indexOf(value.toString()) > -1;
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
    <div class="filter-list-container m-top">
      <div
        *ngFor="let assignment of (filterService.getFilter(filterType.FILTER_ASSIGNMENT).items.ToArray() | filterQuery: filterOptions.assignments | sortBy: configService.config.sortUserBy:'assignment')">
        <mat-checkbox
          [checked]="assignment.id | checkActiveCheckbox:filterService.filterAssignment:filterService.filterAssignment.length"
          [ngClass]="{ 'checkbox-ie': platform.TRIDENT }"
          (change)="filterBy(filterType.FILTER_ASSIGNMENT, assignment.id, filterService.filterAssignment, assignment.name)"
          [value]="assignment.id">
          <div class="assigned">
            <user-image [inline]="true" [user]="assignment.assignment"></user-image>
            <p class="assigned-name">{{ assignment.name }}</p>
          </div>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
```